# Magento admin grid in a form with checkboxes and dropdown-selects

Tags: magento, csv, import, grid, admin

I have to import a CSV where it's column-position is not fixed and contain unwanted headers and invalid rows. Therefore I need a preview on first 10 rows of the CSV after upload and set the rules what and how to import, then do the database import.

[image: Magento Admin Grid in a form]

Options here are **column-assigning**, **required** (skip the row if field is required but empty) and **skip-row**.

Magento grid should looks like:
[image: Magento Admin Grid in a form preview]

I've read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19428/wrap-the-admin-grid-in-form or [Tutorial on Grid Serializer](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid/), but I still cannot add the options like column-assigning, required into the same grid...

One thinking is separate **column-assigning** and **required** as a form on the top, and **skip-row** as a massaction in grid. Then, when clicked submit, use js to gather options in both form and grid-massaction.

Any better way?

Comment: Have you looked at Magmi? It has an input limiter plugin that allows you to ignore rows (for example, in my csv files I set all SKUs for rows I want to ignore to begin with QQQQ but there are other options that may work for you).

Comment: They are not imported as store products, but into a customized products table in database. It's like importer products since we have few importers so we can show their price in our admin product page, etc.

I don't think Magmi can import data to a customize table right? And Magmi is too complained for a general staff to use.

Comment: Ah! I thought you were importing into normal products. Magmi looks a little more complicated but if set up correctly, all a user has to do is choose their file and then run the import.

Comment: Yea so guess not easy way or already implemented extension for it?
That's somehow I don't like Magento, this was easily done in osCommerce...